# RxJava2, Retrofit - doOnNext, doAfterNext, doOnComplete doesn't call

Tags: java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I try to get some data from server.

```
Observable<List<Countries>> backendObservable = mCountriesApi.getCountries()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

backendObservable.doOnNext(list -> Log.d(TAG, "doOnNext"));
backendObservable.doAfterNext(list -> Log.d(TAG, "doAfterNext"));
backendObservable.doOnComplete(() -> Log.d(TAG, "doOnComplete"));

backendObservable.subscribe(new Observer<List<Country>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<Country> value) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doOnNext"));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
```

It's works, I receive data into "onNext". But methods doOnNext, doAfterNext, doOnComplete doesn't call. 
What i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it right up until `observeOn`, what happened? You have to chain operators on `Observable` because they are immutable dataflow plans:

```
backendObservable = backendObservable.doOnNext(list -> Log.d(TAG, "doOnNext"));
backendObservable = backendObservable.doAfterNext(list -> Log.d(TAG, "doAfterNext"));
backendObservable = backendObservable.doOnComplete(() -> Log.d(TAG, "doOnComplete"));
```

or more concisely

```
Observable<List<Countries>> backendObservable = mCountriesApi.getCountries()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnNext(list -> Log.d(TAG, "doOnNext"));
        .doAfterNext(list -> Log.d(TAG, "doAfterNext"));
        .doOnComplete(() -> Log.d(TAG, "doOnComplete"));
        .subscribe(...);
```